# How do you create dynamic error pages?

Tags: error-templates

I want to have one template handle all of my error pages (instead of creating 404.html, 500.html, &c.).

Answer (score 4):

A big thanks to Michael Rog (@rog) for the answer on Slack. You can create a catch-all error template with the name `error` (using whatever file ext works for you). That template also has access to a variable called `code` that tells you what kind of error it is. In my case, I'm using it to display [HTTP Cats](https://http.cat/).

Comment: (p.s. You can customize the location for your error templates by changing the `errorTemplatePrefix` setting in the [Craft General Config](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings).)